# jQuery - Get a selection based on value

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is painfully simple but I just can seem to find it.

I need to get a selection of textboxes from their value.  I don't need the value, I need the elements. I want something like:

```
$(".ProductCode [value:'hideme']").hide();
```

I end up with

```
unrecognized expression: [value:'hideme']
```

btw,

```
$(".ProductCode").each(function() { if ($(this).val() == 'hideme') $(this).hide(); });
```

Is working but it doesn't seem very clean.

Comment: There's no need to use `each()`. When you select elements, you'll preform `hide()` on all the selected elements. I've edited my answer to include a jsFiddle example that hides 2 text boxes at once.

Comment: ok, not only did I have a : instead of an =
but I had a space in there too.  Thanks to both, I gave it to @peter-ajtai for the jsFiddle example. but +1 to both.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) of jQuery

```
$(".ProductCode[value='hideme']").hide();
```

To be more precise, you could also use the [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/):

```
$("input[class='ProductCode'][value='hideme']").hide();
```

The difference between the two is that the first selects all elements with a certain class and value. The second only selects all INPUTs with a certain class and value.

This selectors will select **all** of the applicable elements. So that `hide()` function will hide all of the elements. So there is no need to "manually" iterate through the selected elements with `each()` or other things.. `hide()` automatically does that for you.

[**Here is a live example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/PW4kq/)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$(".ProductCode[value='hideme']").hide();
```

See [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)  in the jQuery docs for more details.

Comment: wow, I should have seen that.  So I'm not getting the error anymore, but I'm not getting anything selected either.  Is there a list of the attributes, or is it the HTML attributes specifically that jQuery is referring to?

Comment: Thanks Justin, I got it, the space was throwing me off as well.