# How to get the id of this div based upon search the inner html value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the div id based upon the value "IBC-CW1 -DE-02A"

```
<div id="main">
<div id="hotspot1" class="drawing" data-canvas-width="89.91394117538998" style="left: 1397.52px;top: 1071.92px;font-size: 10.7966px;font-family: monospace;transform: scaleX(1.01043);background-color: #ff0000;">IBC-CW1 -DE-02A</div>
</div>
```

If i use parentnode means I am getting id="main"

How do i get hotspot1

**Update:**

```
var spot.hotspot_hover = "IBC-CW1 -DE-02A"
    $(".textLayer").each(function(){
                $('.drawing').css('background-color','transparent');

                if($(this).html().indexOf(spot.hotspot_hover) > -1){
                var cont_redirect = $(this).parent()
                console.log(cont_redirect[0])
                $(cont_redirect).css('background-color','#ff0000');
                $('#content-wrapper').animate({scrollTop: cont_redirect[0].offsetTop+300},'slow');
                }
            });
```

Now I have to give background color for that content

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462059/jquery-get-a-selection-based-on-value for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the follwing jquery code

```
var divId = $("div.drawing:contains('IBC-CW1 -DE-02A')").attr('id');
console.log(divId);
```